# rpmbuild creates tmp files and fails due to 'Permission denied' when trying to remove them

Tags: java, rpm, rpmbuild

#### Background

I'm trying to build a simple rpm which just copies some web app source files to an install directory. The web app is written in Java, and is provided by a vendor (i.e it's not written by me).

The rpm fails to build due to the error described below. However, I have successfully built a nearly identical rpm for another Java-based web app from the same vendor. The spec files are the same except for the names of things like the install path and the source file name.

#### Problem

`rpmbuild -v -bb --clean SPECS/web-app.spec` fails with `Permission denied` when it tries to remove some files in `{BUILDROOT}/web-app-1.0/tmp`.

I checked the permissions on the files that `rpmbuild` couldn't remove. Some examples below:

```
-r--r--r--. 1 signer signer  1203 Jan 13  2006 Adler32.class
-r--r--r--. 1 signer signer 19498 Jan 13  2006 Deflate.class
-r--r--r--. 1 signer signer   628 Jan 13  2006 Deflate$Config.class
-r--r--r--. 1 signer signer  8673 Jan 13  2006 InfBlocks.class
```

They have the correct ownership and group for my build user (`signer`), but no write permission.

These files are not part of any process I explicitly defined in my rpm spec. All my spec file does is run `%setup`, make a directory, and copy files into it. The source tarball extracted during `%setup` has the correct permissions for all of its files; I can extract and delete the tree it creates. These files are NOT part of the source tarball. I think the `tmp` files are related to some Java file processing; `rpmbuild` took a long time "repacking" jar files near the end of the build. I'm not sure what purpose that has, and I doubt it's needed for the app I'm deploying.

#### Questions

Can I disable the jar file repacking to fix this? Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you show full permissions for unremovable files, e.g. `ls -al`

Comment: @bbaja42 I added a copy of some of the file permissions to the question. Thanks.

Comment: paranoia: the `.` indicates SELinux; does `ls -alZ` show any unusual context?

Comment: @BRPocock SELinux is set to permissive

Comment: actually, can you add a `chmod u+w -R %{BUILDROOT}` to your `spec`file? (is the problem that the directory itself is mode 0555?)

Comment: @BRPocock Good suggestion, but it doesn't work since the tmp files are created and deleted while `/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars` is running. The files aren't `rm`ed normal cleanup. I can't get `chmod` to intercept the process. I ran `watch ls tmp/` and each jar is unpacked to a temp folder, processed, and then the temp folder is removed (or fails to be removed) before the next jar.

Comment: unpack the jar yourself, change permissions, and replace? *gag* :-(

Comment: @BRP Besides disabling jar repacking, that looks like the only way to go. I should be able to do that in the spec file. You should post that as an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution ended up being to disable jar repacking by putting the following define in my spec file: `%define __jar_repack %{nil}`

BRPocock's answer should also work. The reason I disabled jar repacking instead of repacking the jars myself as BRPocock suggested is because `rpmbuild` takes almost 10 minutes to build with jar repacking enabled, but only a minute with it disabled.

Comment: I've stumbled upon this question because I have the same problem. Important to know is why we need JAR repackaging anyway. TL;DR: If you build noarch RPM packages, you won't need it. Otherwise, you might need it. There's a good explanation in this mailing list: https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-devel-java-list/2008-September/msg00040.html

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, looks like the `.jar` probably contains directories with no write permissions, so under the circumstances … extract the contents of the affected `jar`s yourself, change the permissions `+w`, and recompress them … :-/